# Magento giving error on Checkout Page "Date Of Birth" does not fit the entered date format

Tags: magento

Magento giving error on Checkout Page "Date Of Birth" does not fit the entered date format.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

// Try below instruction and check.

```
Navigate to Customers -> Attributes -> Manage Customer Attributes. Search for attribute with code “dob” and click on displayed row to edit attribute properties.

Set Input/Output filter to “Normalize Date” value and save the attribute.

Clear cache and do the indexing if required..
```

Comment: but input/output filter is disabled or non editable there